# Conditional formatting custom formula based on calculation

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I could use some help with conditional formatting in Google Sheets using a custom formula based on a percentage calculation.

I want to format the background of cell D3 if the value of D3 amounts to less than 15% of B3.

In other words: highlight D3 if the amount of type A hours (D3) make up less than 15% of the total hours (B3).

[image: Q51180117 example]

I guess it might be simple, but I have tried a lot of different ways without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select D3 and apply a CF formula rule of:

```
=D3<0.15*B3
```